# Fisher's Test or chi-squared Test Rstudio

Tags: r

This question uses the data file at [https://people.ucsc.edu/~mclapham/eart125/data/georoc.csv](https://people.ucsc.edu/%7Emclapham/eart125/data/georoc.csv)

**Rhyolites can be divided into high-silica types (rhyolites with greater than 75% SiO2) and more typical rhyolites (75% or less SiO2). Does the proportion of rhyolite types differ significantly between intraplate and convergent margin tectonic settings? Enter the p-value below:**

I tried to group the information together with the following code:

```
kick <- matrix(c(georoc$tectonic.setting == "Intraplate" | georoc$tectonic.setting == "Convergent margin", georoc$SIO2), ncol = 2)
chisq.test(kick)
```

and this is what I got

```
Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  kick
X-squared = 380.59, df = 999, p-value = 1
Warning message:
In chisq.test(ckok) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

What did I do wrong and how should I solve it? I am new to R.

Comment: what makes you think it is wrong?

Comment: I got the p-value = 1 which should be <1

Comment: why should it be less than 1?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is correct but have no idea about this particular domain, so just wanted to caveat that!

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- read_csv('https://people.ucsc.edu/%7Emclapham/eart125/data/georoc.csv')

data_tidy <- data %>% 
  filter(rock.type == "Rhyolite") %>% 
  mutate(high_SiO2 = SIO2 > 75) %>% 
  select("setting" = tectonic.setting, "type" = rock.type, high_SiO2) %>% 
  group_by(setting, type) %>% 
  count(high_SiO2) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  filter(setting %in% c("Convergent margin", "Intraplate")) %>% 
  select(-type) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = high_SiO2, values_from = n) %>% 
  select(setting, "low_SiO2" = `FALSE`, "high_SiO2" = `TRUE`) %>% 
  column_to_rownames(var = "setting") %>% 
  as.matrix()
```

Doing so gives this output:

```
                  low_SiO2 high_SiO2
Convergent margin       62        10
Intraplate              43        22
```

We can then run:

```
chisq.test(data_tidy)
```

... to get:

```
    Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity
    correction

data:  data_tidy
X-squared = 6.5263, df = 1, p-value = 0.01063
```

I was originally concerned that I'd mixed-up the rows and columns of the matrix, but I don't think that matters in this test.